# Toad for Oracle: Procedures, Packages, Job, and DBMS_SCHEDULER

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, plsql, jobs, toad

If I have about 10 queries which contain subqueries, would it be a best practice to contain all of them in one procedure? This script creates a small fraction of the data required for a report.

```
DROP TABLE TEST1;
CREATE TABLE TEST1 AS (
SELECT 
C.DATE,
C.ITEM,   
(SELECT name FROM name_codes WHERE code = C.DEPARTMENT) AS DEPARTMENT,
C.BUSINESS
FROM LOGS C));
```

That's a fraction of it but the code more or less creates tables, filters fields, and combines outputs until the desired result. I am looking to automate data input for other scripts as well. Each script calculates a KPI and would be its own procedure. Then all of those procedures would be wrapped into a package.

That package will be scheduled as a job through `DBMS_SCHEDULER`. Does this sound like the correct course of action? If so, can I call an existing script to create a procedure or would I need to paste the PLSQL into the procedure script? For the moment, I just want to test the first script as a procedure which is scheduled as a job through `DBMS_SCHEDULER`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If so, can I call an existing script to create a procedure or would I
>   need to paste the PLSQL into the procedure script?

Both works.

[DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/DBMS_SCHEDULER.html#GUID-7E744D62-13F6-40E9-91F0-1569E6C38BBC)

The type of the job (`job_type`) can be `PLSQL_BLOCK` or `STORED_PROCEDURE` as well.

For `PLSQL_BLOCK`, you can specify an anonymous block, a piece of PL/SQL code such as `begin ... end;`.

For `STORED_PROCEDURE`, you can specify the name of the stored procedure to call.